# Concatenating two lists in an Array, Separated by a Period

Tags: python, arrays

Here's what I'm trying to do:
Say I have an array:

```
import numpy as np
a = ([['jon','jan','tom','sam'] , ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'] , ['Red', 
'Blu', 'Gre', 'Yel']]);
np.transpose(a);
```

What I want to do is concatenate columns 1 and 3 in a new 4x1 array, b, so that I get the following output:

```
   b = ['jon.Red'
         'jan.Blu'
         'tom.Gre'
         'sam.Yel']
```

What's the best method in python to take columns 1 and 3 and join them, separating the two strings using a period?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
b = ['{}.{}'.format(x, y) for x, _, y in zip(*a)]
```

[String formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting), [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) are used here and concepts worth reading up on.

On a side note, Python does not require semi-colons and the outer parentheses in `a = ([...])` are superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use list comprehension and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> [e0 + '.' + e1 for (e0, e1) in zip(a[0], a[2])]
['jon.Red', 'jan.Blu', 'tom.Gre', 'sam.Yel']
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can do something like this:

```
a = ([['jon','jan','tom','sam'] , ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'] , ['Red', 
'Blu', 'Gre', 'Yel']])

final = [".".join(k) for k in zip(a[0], a[-1])]
print(final)
```

Output:

```
['jon.Red', 'jan.Blu', 'tom.Gre', 'sam.Yel']
```